# Box API Node.js cant upload file 404 Error

Tags: node.js, box, boxapiv2

I cant upload file with Box API my code:

```
var sdk = new BoxSDK({
  clientID: BOX_clientID,
  clientSecret: BOX_clientSecret
});





// Create a basic API client
var client = sdk.getBasicClient(BOX_accesstoken);



var fileData = fs.createReadStream('C:\\Exports\\test.txt')

client.files.uploadFile('123', 'test.txt', fileData, function(err, file) {
if (err){
console.log('err: ' + err);
}
else{
console.log('file uploaded: ' + file);  
}
});


// Get some of that sweet, sweet data!
client.users.get(client.CURRENT_USER_ID, null, function(err, currentUser) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('Hello, ' + currentUser.name + '!');
});
```

This is the output

Hello, UserXYZ!
err: Error: Unexpected API Response [404 Not Found] (not_found: "Not Found")

Also I really don´t understand how to refresh my token with node.js the code from the docs is not working for me. Has somebody working sample codes for uploading files and how I can endless use a token I don´t want to enter new access codes everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to client.files.upload needs to be a valid folder_id so I believe that's why the [404 Not Found] appears.  So you can try something like '0'.

Here's an example using jwt and it will take care of the token refresh.

```
// --------------- jwt --------------------------
var BoxSDK = require('box-node-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx',
  CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxx',
  PUBLIC_KEY_ID = 'xxxx',
  PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = 'xxxx',
  PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE = 'xxxx',
  ENTERPRISE_ID = 'xxxx';

var sdk = new BoxSDK({
    clientID: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    appAuth: {
      keyID: PUBLIC_KEY_ID,
      privateKey: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)),
      passphrase: PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE
    }
});

// --------------- your code ---------------------
var client = sdk.getAppAuthClient('enterprise', ENTERPRISE_ID);

var fileData = fs.createReadStream('C:\\Exports\\test.txt')
client.files.uploadFile('0', 'test.txt', fileData, function(err, file) {
if (err){console.log('err: ' + err);
}
else{console.log('file uploaded: ' + file);  
}
});


// Get some of that sweet, sweet data!
client.users.get(client.CURRENT_USER_ID, null, function(err, currentUser) {
  if(err) throw err;  console.log('Hello, ' + currentUser.name + '!');
});
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the sample code. But how do you generate the private key for this PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = 'C:\\box cloud\\key.key'. I created myself a key file with sublime and copied the private key from the generated json from BOX. I replace \n with real line breaks and added ^M  each line end. But also without ^M I get this error.

Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Comment: EDIT: When I add the private key with the \n in original way from json to privateKey: then the error is away but then I get Error: Unexpected API Response [400 Bad Request]

Comment: Also if I use key.pem file without \n but I replace it with real line breaks. I get the Bad request error

Comment: here is my code I tried https://pastebin.com/iFYJetp8  -  Same result if I would try to upload file. Also I cant make console.log on the body because body is unknown. I google it and they all say the data that is send to server is malformed. But seems correct for me? maybe wrong codec of the pem file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see what's going on.  If you're using Box's generated keys, do the following.

1. create a directory called config
2. rename Box's config file to default.json
3. And then the code looks like this...

   var BoxSDK = require('box-node-sdk');
   var config = require('config');
   var fs = require('fs');
   var path = require('path');

   var sdk = new BoxSDK({
       clientID: config.get('boxAppSettings.clientID'),
       clientSecret: config.get('boxAppSettings.clientSecret'),
       appAuth: {
         keyID: config.get('boxAppSettings.appAuth.publicKeyID'),
         privateKey: config.get('boxAppSettings.appAuth.privateKey'),
         passphrase: config.get('boxAppSettings.appAuth.passphrase'),
         expirationTime: 60,
         verifyTimestamp: false
       }
   });

   var client = sdk.getAppAuthClient('enterprise', "xxxxx");

   var fileData = fs.createReadStream('/users/kdomen/Downloads/test.txt')
   client.files.uploadFile('0', 'test.txt', fileData, function(err, file) {
     if (err){
       console.log('err: ' + err);
     }
     else {
       console.log('file uploaded: ' + file);
     }
   });

   // Get some of that sweet, sweet data!
   client.users.get(client.CURRENT_USER_ID, null, function(err, currentUser) {
     if(err) throw err;  console.log('Hello, ' + currentUser.name + '!');
   });

Comment: I download the config module and then included like you told me. I get again 400 bad request error. I used this code https://pastebin.com/KJPkVTtq so the same like you postet. I also tried to manually load the json fs.readFileSync and then enter the details with config.clientID as example but also 400 bad request error. Also same result with turned off firewall.

Comment: I will try now to create a fresh project. And try it again

Comment: same result with fresh created app and I deleted the old one. I choosed enterprise option at the beginning when you create new app and you can choose between 3 options. Any other idead how I can get it to work? or do you have a refresh option for oAuth2 ? This are my settings http://imgur.com/a/sSSQj I also choosed enterprise and not application as option in this screen.

Comment: Did you authorize the app in enterprise settings?

Comment: What do you mean at which url? or can you send me screen pls?

Comment: Go to admin console -> enterprise settings (the dial icon) -> Apps -> Authorize New Apps and put in your client_id

Comment: Yes this was the problem. I thought the only settings would be at the developer site developer.box.com - THANK YOU SO MUCH for the help. I learned a lot since we wrote. also this config plugin is nice. have a nice day

Comment: Hey I wrote you on support.box.com a private message. I have sadly I second problem would be awesome if you could help me again. thank you

Comment: Sure just post it as another question here in stackoverlow and I'll add an answer