# Box API can´t see my uploaded file

Tags: node.js, box-api, boxapiv2

Related to this post [Box API Node.js cant upload file 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396100/box-api-node-js-cant-upload-file-404-error)
I use the awnser code from below to auth my app
It works with showing my username so auth successfull.
If I look in my task manager I can see that there is outgoing traffic / uptime 
speed so the file will be uploaded in the function after the user check. And I also enter the else area so successfull upload. But if I look into my box website area I cant see the file. When I try to run the script again I get 409 error that the file already exist. Any Idea why I cant see the file at box.com? I manually added response and body for debug but they are not found. Also I enabled all scopes at developer area of box.com

Successfull log in to box.com - Your APP Name: xxxxxxx!
file uploaded: [object Object]
else body: undefined
else response: undefined

This is my code

```
// BOX
var BoxSDK = require('box-node-sdk');



var config = require('config')





var sdk = new BoxSDK({ 
  clientID: config.get('boxAppSettings.clientID'),
  clientSecret: config.get('boxAppSettings.clientSecret'),
  appAuth: { 
    keyID: config.get('boxAppSettings.appAuth.publicKeyID'),
    privateKey: config.get('boxAppSettings.appAuth.privateKey'),
    passphrase: config.get('boxAppSettings.appAuth.passphrase'),
    expirationTime: 60,
    verifyTimestamp: false 
  } 
});


var client = sdk.getAppAuthClient('enterprise', "2xxxxxxxx5");


//Get some of that sweet, sweet data! 
client.users.get(client.CURRENT_USER_ID, null, function(err, currentUser) { 
  if(err) throw err; 
  console.log('Hello, ' + currentUser.name + '!'); 
});

    var fileData = fs.createReadStream('C:\\Exports\\box2.zip');
client.files.uploadFile('0', 'box2.zip', fileData, function(err, file, body, response) {
if (err){
console.log('err while upload file: ' + err)
console.log('if body: ' + body);
console.log('if response: ' + response);
}
else{
console.log('file uploaded: ' + file);
console.log('else body: ' + body);
console.log('else response: ' + response);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're file uploaded to the service account created by the app.  If you go to Admin Console -> Content Manager then type "automation" and select the automation user associated with your app, you'll see your content there.

Comment: omg yes you are right. this is very mystical :D Is there a way to upload always with the administrator that I can see the files directly when I logged in to my box account?

Comment: You can add the admin as a collaborator to a folder created in the service acccount.

Comment: thank you for the help dude :) but where is this service account area.- I already searched at the normal box.com area and in the developer area but there are so many options not sure which you mean. can you send me a URL or screen please that I see what you mean. would be awesome

Comment: If you post this as a new question, I can post the solution as code.  Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494079/box-api-upload-files-to-admin-account-instead-of-app