# Box API upload files to admin account instead of APP

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

Hey I use the Box API and I successfull to upload my files but they are stored at the app storage folder. If you would go to the admin-console and then click the folder Icon you can see the admin folder and then the folder of the created app. How can I change the path that every upload will go to the admin folder that if I relog to box.com I would see all my files in the home folder instead of going to the admin-console every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
    var client = sdk.getAppAuthClient('enterprise', ENTERPRISE_ID);

   //filter_term == admin to share the folder with
   client.enterprise.getUsers({filter_term: 'ken.domen@nike.com'}, function(err, users) {
   var userId = users.entries[0].id;
   client.folders.create('0', 'New Folder', function(err, newFolder) {
    client.collaborations.createWithUserID(userId, newFolder.id, client.collaborationRoles.VIEWER, function(err, collaboration) {
        console.log(err);

        var fileData = fs.createReadStream('/users/kdomen/Downloads/test.txt')
        client.files.uploadFile(newFolder.id, 'test.txt', fileData, function(err, file) {
          if (err){
            console.log('err: ' + err);
          }
          else{
            console.log('file uploaded: ' + file);  
          }
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: hey thank you for the awnser. I will test it to tomorrow and give report.

Comment: you are my hero dog! As far as I saw box supported no tracking from the upload progress. like at googledrive you can make req.connection.bytesWritten as example. Or is there a way you know? Btw did you also work with onedrive API?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this.  Sorry!

Comment: I got a new problem maybe you have also sample codes for delete folder and list all item froms the root incl. folders. Doesn´t need to be compatible with the admin code from above can work with the default app storage. But I would prefer any variante you have. If you have both please send both https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517682/box-api-node-js-how-to-create-delete-folder-and-display-all-files-inclusive-fol