# Box API node.js how to delete folder and display all files inclusive folders

Tags: node.js, box-api, box

I need working sample codes for delete a folder and list all items + folders in the root. I use node.js and as example I can create folder with

```
client.folders.create('0', 'New Folder', function(err, newFolder) {
if(err) throw err;
console.log('dff')
});
```

But if I try then related to docs client.folders.delete

```
client.folders.delete('0', 'New Folder', function(err, newFolder) {
 if(err) throw err;
 console.log('dff')
});
```

I get error "Unexpected API Response [403 Forbidden] (access_denied_insufficient_permissions: "Access denied - insufficient permission")". If I would remove 0 then I get rejection error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var client = sdk.getAppAuthClient('enterprise', ENTERPRISE_ID);

client.folders.getItems('0', null, function(err, items) {
  items.entries.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element)

  if (element.type == 'folder') {
      console.log('folder: ' + element.type);
      client.folders.delete(element.id, {recursive: true}, function(err, data) {
   });
  }
  else {
      console.log('file: ' + element.type);
      client.files.delete(element.id, {recursive: true}, function(err, data) {
     });
  }
  }, this);
})
```

Comment: thank you once again <3 :) What mean "this" in the foreach loop?